# Single record callout to run once in the near future

Tags: callout, schedulebatch

I am trying to find the best solution to my problem below and I'm feeling like my current solution can't be the easiest way to go about it. Let me know if I'm missing something or if this does sound reasonable.

We have Lightning Sync set up to sync Outlook with Salesforce calendars and I am trying to make sure our room resources also stay in sync, which I don't see a way to do that without creating a new user dedicated to each room resource. So I am using Microsoft's Graph API to send attendee updates. But when adding a new event in Salesforce, the event in Outlook won't exist until Lightning Sync can do it's thing first (is there a way we can tell when Microsoft responds that the sync completed?). If I try to update the attendees too soon, I won't be able to find a meeting yet to update. **So I want to delay the update for a short time until I can be reasonably confident that the event will exist.**

I don't see an easy way to delay something or schedule something to run once apart from using the Batchable interface. So I am updating a hidden field on the events to be updated and then scheduling a batch job shortly thereafter, to find the least recently updated event with this hidden field set to true. But my use case is really meant to be used one-by-one, so I'm already a bit hesitant to use something called "batch" for singular calls. And this seems like an inefficient way to go about this. And this doesn't happen often enough that scheduling something on a recurring basis makes sense. Are there any other better ways you would recommend for this use case?

Comment: [record-triggered flows with scheduled paths supports minutes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_scheduled_paths_minutes.htm&type=5&release=234) as offset in winter 22.  Use the target object = `Event`

Comment: Hmmm that's a really good alternative. But I'm assuming there's no option to do something similar all within Apex? Feels like I should be able to do this in a few lines rather than creating a whole new batch or a new flow :(

Comment: Unless Lightning Sync offers a callback to tell SFDC when it is done, you are going to be "intelligently guessing" when the sync is done. The only feature in apex to schedule a transaction x minutes from now is the cron expression in scheduled apex or scheduled batch.  Future and queueable may execute within seconds of the Event DML so that could be too fast. The flow is pretty trivial and you could easily make config-only changes to adjust the offset minutes based on experience

Comment: Note Lightning Sync is deprecated so investing a lot here may not be worth it

Comment: Got it - thanks @cropredy that's exactly what I was hoping was not the case "The only feature in apex to schedule a transaction x minutes from now is the cron expression in scheduled apex or scheduled batch". If you want to throw it below as an answer, I'll mark that one!

However unlikely it seems, I'm still hoping they reverse course on Einstein Activity Capture, but at the very least, we have a pretty decent runway left with Lightning Sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Lightning Sync doesn't offer a callback to SFDC when it has completed so you need to "intelligently guess" when it would be safe to do the meeting updates.

### Options

- **Record-triggered flows with scheduled paths**

Winter 22 offers the ability to run these at an offset of minutes from some datetime on the target object. And, of course Flows are bulkified and any invocable apex they call would also be bulkified.

However, you'd need a fallback strategy in case the Lightning Sync isn't finished. Perhaps by toggling your pending work flag and adjusting the reference datetime (thus scheduling a new flow interview).

- **Scheduled Apex, Scheduled Batch**

These tools support cron expressions (Scheduled Apex) and offset in minutes (Scheduled Batch). There are [limits to be cognizant of](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).  You mentioned using a hidden field to denote need to do work. With this approach, I'd have a scheduled batchable start at minute X and in its finish, reschedule itself for +m minutes later.

The advantage of the batch job is that it will deal with delays in the Lightning Sync because it will keep picking up records that have pending work

- **future/queueable/platform events**

These are all asynchronous and *can/may/will* run very soon after the initiating transaction ends. Thus, they might discover the Lightning Sync hasn't finished. If so, you'll need a fallback strategy (like chained queueables)

- **Apex wait loop**

You can run a tight loop in APEX to consume, say, 8 CPU secs and then try the callout. But again, you need a fallback strategy if the Lightning Sync isn't done (e.g. start a queueable that in turn does a CPU wait loop).  This is a bit hacky and not recommended best practice for multi-tenant environments.